# Return data from Async function React Native Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux, async-await

I am having trouble with accessing the data after fetching it with `SecureStore` in Expo for react-native.

Here is the simple code:

```
const infoofuser = SecureStore.getItemAsync('userInfo').then(value =>
  console.log(`this is the vlaue from infouser: ${value}`),
);
console.log(`infoouser: ${JSON.stringify(infoofuser)}`);
```

the first `infoofuser` constant definition returns the object of the intended data.

```
console.log(`infoouser: ${JSON.stringify(infoofuser)}`);
```

however returns `{"_U":0,"_V":0,"_W":null,"_X":null}` which U understand is a promise. I would like to simply get the data that comes from the SecureStore call and use it to set my initialState in redux.

```
const infoofuser = SecureStore.getItemAsync('userInfo').then(value =>
  value
);
```

this does not work either to access the data

Answer (score 0):

You can use async method using async/await. Try this:

```
const userInfo = useSelector(state => state.userInfo);

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const infoofuser = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userInfo');
    console.log('infoofuser:', infoofuser)
    /// strore on redux
  } catch (err) {
     // handle error
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  getData()
}, [])

if (!userInfo) return null

//render something else
```

You can check the [Expo Secure Store](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) docs for reference.

Comment: Sorry, my question refers to how I can get the result of the getData() function and then use it somewhere else. This method works in the sense that I can see the value of `infoofuser` however when `let a = getData().then(value => value)` still results in a promise

Comment: may i know why u need .then when we receive the data using async/await directly??

Comment: u need to put await before getData otherwise u are assigning the reference of the async function , u are not waiting for the async function(ie: getData) to resolve the the data from the secure storage

Comment: The reason is that I would like to use the object I am getting from the async call somewhere else and set that that to the initialstate in redux. Here is the code according to your suggestion: `let a = async () => await getData();

console.log(`this is a: ${a}`);`

Comment: And here is the result: `this is a: function a() {
    return _regenerator.default.async(function a$(_context3) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context3.prev = _context3.next) {
          case 0:
            _context3.next = 2;
            return _regenerator.default.awrap(getData());

          case 2:
            return _context3.abrupt("return", _context3.sent);

          case 3:
          case "end":
            return _context3.stop();
        }
      }
    }, null, null, null, Promise);
  }`

Comment: i have updated the code to use for redux check the above answer

Comment: This is for usage in screens and components. To state more clearly, I am trying to get this data as `initialState` in `store.js` of redux so that I can load the data before the user enters the app. If this was in a web app with `React`, I would go ahead and use `localStorage` and set that to `initialState` of the `store`. However, as `SecureStore` or `AsyncStorage` are asynchronous, I am having a difficult time accessing the return value to set it to the `initalState` in `store.js` of Redux

Comment: u can store the use info in reducer directly and persist the the reducer using redux-persist so u can get the data when the app launches

Comment: How would you go about storing the latest localStorage (or in this case SecureStore data)  data in the reducer? Till the time it fetches from SecureStore, store.js is already rendered. That is why I thought I have to somehow set an `initialState`